# Running a command from C++

Tags: c++, linux, command-line

To get the cpu info from C++ in Linux, I simply use:

> if (!system("cat /proc/cpuinfo")) cout << "Error" << endl;

UPDATE: The problem is that I get no out put

Comment: ... and the billion dollar question is?

Comment: What part of the message don't you understand?

Comment: I get no output. the output is ignored

Comment: You might want to use `strace -f` to find out what system calls and child processes your program is running...

Answer (score 3):

It's telling you that `system` returns a value, and you're not checking it, so (in this case) if `system` fails, you won't know about it.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to get information about the CPU programmatically on Linux (and not just display `/proc/cpuinfo` on the *stdout* terminal, like your call to `system` does), you should better read the file `/proc/cpuinfo` like e.g.

```
  ifstream fcp("/proc/cpuinfo");
  std::string lin;
  while (!fcp.eof()) {
     lin = fcp.getline ();
     // parse appropriately the file fcp, e.g.
     if (lin.find("vendor_id") >= 0) 
       // do something useful
```

The above code snippet is incomplete. You have to complete it to extract from `/proc/cpuinfo` the information you really want.

Of course you could read `/proc/cpuinfo` by some other ways (e.g. `fopen`, `fgets`, `sscanf` à la C).... If you really wanted to read the output of some command (in your case it is useless) consider `popen`

You may be happy by just calling the [uname(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/uname.2.html) syscall (which provides much less info than `/proc/cpuinfo`).

---

Googling for *cpufreq* or *cpufrequtils* gives [this](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3amafyVZXA5NQJ%3apublib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxinfo/v3r0m0/topic/liaai/cpufreq/liaai-cpufreq_pdf.pdf%20&hl=fr&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEEShgawrpTTCM60Zq2URdRADq2dk4eUj4NjCWs9AYcMQI54-YDd8UkciAf3wrxkrXM2AaUCRD5-lxQ8uLFihSE6T4M5QMfdU90mAPA0f6XRYc44gr9EytmkJXGD0zZRzPeFlXLlUH&sig=AHIEtbSq3LGZkpcBGvd0Usw3CrZ7W-2r4A)

Comment: Thanks! At least one person read my first question that I said "I get no information". I don't really know what you mean by "do something useful" though. I just want to see all the information. What Can I do? Why my code doesn't show anything?

Comment: What information from `/proc/cpuinfo` do you want, and what for? If you want to display all of `/proc/cpuinfo` to the user, just read that file as I suggested and display every line of it, e.g. add `std::out << lin << std::endl;` after the `lin = fcp.getline();` statement.

Comment: Then you need to parse `/proc/cpuinfo` and find the `cpu MHz` line, but there are other ways to get that information.... (maybe using some ACPI library or the `libcpufreq` , or reading some files under `/sys/devices/system/cpu/` ....)

Comment: about your code: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::getline()’

Comment: Read http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/ & http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/ ; maybe your GCC compiler version is too old (current is 4.7); or parse the `/proc/cpuinfo` file by other means (you could even use old `fopen` and `fgets` and `sscanf` ....)

Answer (score 1):

The function returns a value indicating whether the call was successful or not.

Your program is ignoring this value, which could lead to potential problems.

This is why you get a compiler warning.

Answer (score 0):

It's a compiler warning telling you that your code may not be what you *intended* to write.  The `system` function in C++ returns an `int` value *generally* containing the status code of the command you ran with `system`.

In this case, if that number is not 0 (ie `if(system("cat /proc/cpuinfo") != 0)`), you might want error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Linux has a unique open function called `popen` which allows you to hook into the stdout of a terminal command.

you can use the following code to read any output from a terminal command:

```
FILE *pF = popen(aCmd, "r");

if(!pF)
{
    return "ERROR";
}

char cChar = '\0';
std::string rtnStr = "";

while(!feof(pF))
{
    cChar = fgetc(pF);

    if(cChar == '\n')
    {
        break;
    }

    rtnStr += cChar;
}
```

And using the command `cat /proc/cpuinfo` for CPU info. You can also add `| grep` followed by something like "MHz", "model", or "cores" for specifics.